# set text in Button click in custom adapter failed

Tags: android, textview, custom-adapter

I'm clicking a button in between my items in my listview and everything works well, add a step that was set text to a TextView and failure.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtOrden"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_green_small"
    android:maxHeight="48dp"
    android:maxWidth="80dp"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:text="Validar"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMensaje"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:text="SDSDSDS"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textSize="10dp" />
```

Code in custom adapter :

```
TextView m = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtMensaje);
m.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
m.setText("E-ticket validado");
```

Error :

```
08-11 11:56:10.445: E/AndroidRuntime(28547): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 11:56:10.445: E/AndroidRuntime(28547): Process: com.eventrid.scanner, PID: 28547
08-11 11:56:10.445: E/AndroidRuntime(28547): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
08-11 11:56:10.445: E/AndroidRuntime(28547): at com.google.zxing.client.android.CustomListViewAdapter$1.onClick(CustomListViewAdapter.java:148)
```

The strange thing is that I am doing the same with a button but that if it works.

```
Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_big_check);
b.setText("");
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.width = 50;
params.height = 50;
params.rightMargin = 63;
params.topMargin = 10;
params.bottomMargin = 5;
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
b.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Are the button(s) and TextView(s) part of each list item or are they not related to the adapter, i.e. they are outside the listview?

Comment: @jvmk They are part of the layout that takes shape the list, if they have to do

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you. But if you're saying that the button and textview are both part of each list item then please post the entire getView implementation of your custom adapter as well as the entire xml file you use to inflate the view in the getView call.